# Using fill_between in matplotlib multiple times for different ranges

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, anaconda

I have a graph that looks like this:

[image]

The code I used to fill the blue area is:

```
plt.fill_between(x_axis, lower_bound, upper_bound, facecolor='lightblue')
```

I tried to add similar fills for a range above and below these boundaries which were to be colored yellow, but python only renders the above line. The other two lines look like this:

```
plt.fill_between(x_axis, upper_bound, plus, facecolor='yellow')
plt.fill_between(x_axis, lower_bound, upper_bound, facecolor='lightblue')
plt.fill_between(x_axis, minus, lower_bound, facecolor='yellow')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how "plus" and "minus" look like but, in case they indicate the widths of the yellow bands, did you try the following?

```
plt.fill_between(x_axis, upper_bound, upper_bound + plus, facecolor='yellow')
plt.fill_between(x_axis, lower_bound, upper_bound, facecolor='lightblue')
plt.fill_between(x_axis, lower_bound - minus, lower_bound, facecolor='yellow')
```

In particular, make sure that the lower bounds are smaller than the upper bounds.